# How do I debug when using ionic emulate android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I created an application using ionic:

```
ionic start MyFirstApp blank
cd MyFirstApp
ionic serve
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic emulate android
```

Everything is successful except the emulator step. The emulator boots up, but I get "Unfortunately, MyFirstApp has stopped". Everything brand new straight out of the box, no changes to code.

What next? How do I debug what has gone wrong?

**EDIT**
This is the output displayed when I call `ionic build android`:

```
    C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp>ionic build android
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
Buildfile: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MyFirstApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyFirstApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyFirstApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MyFirstApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyFirstApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyFirstApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
      [dex] input: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-3a52ec06bbf9dc987d551c9695e3393a.jar <- C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (12 defs/8.7KiB) with dex B (209 defs/317.1KiB). Result is 221 defs/396.2KiB. Took 0.2s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found Deleted Target File
[apkbuilder] Creating MyFirstApp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\MyFirstApp-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
Using apk: C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Ionic\MyFirstApp\platforms\android\ant-build\MyFirstApp-debug-unaligned.apk
```

**EDIT 2** This is the output from `android list avd`

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: Nexus7
  Device: Nexus 7 (Google)
    Path: C:\Users\Colin\.android\avd\Nexus7.avd
  Target: Android 4.4W (API level 20)
 Tag/ABI: android-wear/armeabi-v7a
    Skin: WVGA800
```

Comment: What is the output that you are getting from `ionic build android`?

Comment: Your build looks OK. It should work.. I'm afraid I can't help you.  Are you using the latest version of ionic-cli and the latest android SDK?

Comment: Yep From command line `ionic lib` - Latest Ionic version: 1.0.0-beta.13  (released 2014-09-24). Android version not sure how to check but very recently downloaded - path contains `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702`

Comment: post your output from `android list avd` and `ionic emulate android`

Comment: @ashoke I have added my output from `android list avd`. This is how I realised that the emulator was set to target API level 20 but the build was using API level 19. I changed the emulator to 19 and now it works. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure you created the right avd configuration for the emulator.

type `android list avd` and see the output. What is the first avd listed there ? If it shows older API level (for eg: 7)

[image: old api]

API [level 9 and higher is required, API level 15](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) and high preferred. You cannot use API 20 Android Wear AVD, as it is only for testing wear devices.

You can delete the existing avd with `android delete avd -n Name` (replace `Name` with yours).

create one with `android create avd --name test15 --target android-15 --abi x86`

make sure `android list avd` shows your avd is the first listed.

- I followed the same steps, i use windows, my `ionic build android` output is similar to yours; I was able to get `ionic emulate android` working with API-15, please see below:

  [image: ionic emulate android]

Answer (score 10):

A much easier/better solution in my opinion is to use the chrome://inspect tool on chrome.

1. Launch the app on your Android using

   ionic run android
2. Open Chrome and go to: chrome://inspect  -  this will list your connected devices.
3. Inspect the app using chrome dev tools as if you were inspecting any other web page.